# Referring executing jar location

Tags: java, jar, classpath, executable-jar

I have seen similar question in this forum already but none of the answers are working for me. Here is what I'm trying to get: I have an application with multiple classes. I have packaged that as a runnable jar file from eclipse which works fine. The problem is, there will be a properties file present in the same directory where this jar will be present and from one of my java class I have to refer to this property file. The location of the jar file and property file can be dynamic but, they will be in same directory. To achieve this I have tried the following:

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

and

```
MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()
```

But all of this returns only ./ for my case. Please help.

Comment: Im pretty sure that / just is the location where the jar is

Comment: No. The jar is present in a direcorty C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\JarFolder\ABC.jar. When I am executing java -jar "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\JarFolder\ABC.jar" it returns ./

Answer (score 1):

The path gives you the directory or "path part" of the Jar.  If you want the name of the Jar file you need `getFile()` as well.

Comment: MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getFile() also returns ./ Please help.